# Electron dev version and production version are different

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I developed my app with Electron-vue and electron-builder and target OS is Windows exe App.

But I found that in dev mode it works find but When I build it, some functions are not working.

It seems that functions that related with electron-update package are not working.

For example, run with dev mode it seems that text of version is works well with this code. But in Production mode the version seems not working.

However it has some error in dev mode, I dont know why I should put my app-update.yml file in node_modules folder. It should be placed somewhere else because, node_modules folder is ignored by .ignore file. How can I handle app-update.yml directory path?

```
┏ Electron -------------------

  16:46:23.785 > Checking for update

┗ ----------------------------

┏ Electron -------------------

  Window "main-window" was created

┗ ----------------------------

┏ Electron -------------------

  16:46:23.915 > Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\myapp\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\app-update.yml'

┗ ----------------------------

┏ Electron -------------------

  (node:20808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\myapp\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\app-update.yml'

┗ ----------------------------

┏ Electron -------------------

  (node:20808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
  (node:20808) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.       

┗ ----------------------------
```

```
<template>
  <Window title='Program Updater'>
    <div class='wrap' id='currentAppVersion'>
      Current App Version : {{currentAppVersion}}
    </div>
    <div class='wrap' id='checkNewVersion'>
      Latest App Version : {{latestAppVersion}}
    </div>
  </Window>
</template>

<script>
import Window from '@/components/Window'
import Icon from '@/components/Icon'

export default {
  name: 'update-window',

  components: {
    Window,
    Icon
  },
  data () {
    return {
      // appVersion: app.getVersion()
      currentAppVersion: process.env.npm_package_version,
      latestAppVersion: 'Not yet Developed'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**[Dev mode]**
[image]

**[Production mode build]**
[image]

This is my package.json

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "main": "./dist/electron/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node .electron-vue/build.js && electron-builder",
    "build:dir": "node .electron-vue/build.js && electron-builder --dir",
    "build:clean": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=clean node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "build:web": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=web node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "dev": "node .electron-vue/dev-runner.js",
    "dev:tray": "node .electron-vue/dev-runner.js -- --systray",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue -f ./node_modules/eslint-friendly-formatter src",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --ext .js,.vue -f ./node_modules/eslint-friendly-formatter --fix src",
    "pack": "npm run pack:main && npm run pack:renderer",
    "pack:main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors --config .electron-vue/webpack.main.config.js",
    "pack:renderer": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors --config .electron-vue/webpack.renderer.config.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run lint:fix",
    "publish": "build --win -p always",
    "deploy": "electron-builder build --win --publish always"
  },
  "build": {
    "productName": "Geomec Cloud Manager",
    "appId": "com.apps.geomec-cloud-manager",
    "artifactName": "Geomec-Cloud-Manager-Setup-v${version}.${ext}",
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": true,
      "installerIcon": "build/icons/setup-icon.ico",
      "uninstallDisplayName": "Geomec Cloud Manager"
    },
    "directories": {
      "output": "build"
    },
    "files": [
      "dist/electron/**/*"
    ],
    "win": {
      "icon": "build/icons/app-icon.ico"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-log": "^4.3.2",
    "electron-updater": "^4.3.8",
    "electron-window-manager": "github:evsar3/electron-window-manager",
    "uuid": "^7.0.2",
    "v-tooltip": "^2.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-electron": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.3.3",
    "vue-router": "^3.4.3",
    "vue-switches": "^2.0.1",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.24.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-electron": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
 ........
}
```

Comment: are you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to [#4468](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4468), `npm_package_version` is set by npm, not Electron

You should use [`app.getVersion()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetversion) instead

> Returns String - The version of the loaded application. If no version is found in the application's package.json file, the version of the current bundle or executable is returned.